# problem solving for a and b (remainder excersise)

Tags: polynomials

problem solving for a and b (remainder excersise)

I know the remeinder theorem but I cant solve this for a and b. can someone give me a hint?

[image]

g(x) is (x-1)(x-2)

Answer (score 0):

If you divide a polynomial $f(x)$ by $x - k$, then the remainder is $f(k)$.

You also know that the remainder when $f(x) = x^3 - ax + b$ is divided by $g(x) = (x - 1)(x - 2)$ is $r(x) = 4x - 1$.

Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x - 1$ by substituting $1$ into $f(x)$ and $r(x)$.  Equate the two results.

Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x - 2$ by substituting $2$ into $f(x)$ and $r(x)$.  Equate the two results.

That will give you a system of two linear equations in $a$ and $b$.

After you find $a$ and $b$, check your result by dividing $f(x)$ by $g(x)$.  The remainder should be $r(x) = 4x - 1$.